# Translation for a slurred おひゃき

Tags: translation, manga

Said by a girl in the middle of eating breakfast, the full dialogue is:

> おひゃきにいたらいてまふ～

She appears to be sleepy and has a mouth full of food, so parts of the sentence are slurred. She is also a bit messy, as crumbs are strewn about.

I understand the latter half written properly would be いたらいてます, which I interpret as she is in the process of reaching particular state, and that state is indicated by whatever comes before the に particle. But I have no idea what おひゃき translates to or resembles.

Judging by the context I'm guessing it is related to being tidier or more attentive, but my Japanese vocabulary isn't extensive enough to know any similar sounding phrases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be:

> お[先]{さき}にいただいてます。

いたらいています makes no sense. The verb you have in mind must be [至]{いた}る. Its て-form is いたって.

Comment: Seems I need to study up on て-forms, I didn't realize at all that いたら could also be slurred and went right into a pitfall. Thank you

Comment: While I fully agree with this answer, I do find it a bit weird that だ is slurred into ら. I would rather expect the opposite...

Comment: @a20, the さ → ひゃ shift is also a bit weird, no? Given that strangeness, the だ → ら shift seems about the same level of weirdness.  Years ago, my wife had a DoCoMo flip phone with some Java-based OS. with a bear avatar named "Kūman" that would walk onto the screen.  Kūman had a "lisp" of sorts, where all the //s// sounds were rendered as //f// instead.  So Kūman would say things like 「よふぃ！いきまふぉう！」 I wonder if 「おひゃきにいたらいてまふ～」 is a similar kind of "lisp" or "accent"?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi: I would guess that ら sounded kind of like the English /r/ because the food in her mouth prevented the tip of her tongue from touching the ridge of the upper teeth (the alveolar) as required by /d/ or the Japanese /r/. This might also explain the shift from /s/ (alveolar fricative) to /ç/ (palatal fricative) in ひゃ or /ɸ/ (bilabial fricative) in ふ. What I find strange is why she had no trouble with に, た, and て, which also require the tip of the tongue to be touching the alveolar...